# WCF - difference between a behaviour and a contract?

Tags: wcf

In WCF, what is the difference between a **Behaviour** and a **Contract**? From examining the config file, both seem to point to the interface of the service functionality. Why are they both needed?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The Cole's Notes version:

- The **Contract** specifies *what the service actually does*.  In other words, what **Operations** are valid.
- The **Endpoint** specifies an actual *running instance* of the service.  It is the actual "service" in the sense that it *executes*, either as a Windows Service or under IIS.
- The **Service Behavior** defines *how the endpoint interacts with clients*.  Attributes like security, concurrency, caching, logging, etc. - those are all part of the behavior.
- There is also an **Operation Behavior** which is similar to the Service Behavior but only gets applied when a specific *operation* is run.

For more information I suggest you start with the [WCF Architecture Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480210.aspx).

Comment: And also for the difference between endpoint behavior and service behavior: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mahjayar/archive/2006/02/27/540033.aspx

Answer (score 8):

A bit late for an answer but

- as I'm currently struggling with the difference between the two
- and as this is one of the first results on Google
- and because the current answers did not give *me* that *aha* moment

following is in a nutshell what turned the light on for me *(cudo's to Fred Yang)*

**ServiceContract**

- affects the behavior of both client and server
- can apply to both interface and class
- affects the WSDL emitted

**ServiceBehavior**

- only affects the behavior of the server
- only applicable to a class implementation
- does not affect the WSDL

---

From [ServiceContract vs ServiceBehavior](http://blog.semanticsworks.com/2009/03/servicecontract-vs-servicebehavior_1135.html)

> In WCF, ServiceContract attribute affect the behavior of both client
>   and server, while ServiceBehavior only affect the behavior of server.
>   ServiceContract can apply both to interface and class, but
>   ServiceBehavior can only apply to class implementation.
>   ServiceContract affect the wsdl emitted, but ServiceBehavior will not
>   affect wsdl emitted.

Answer (score 7):

The Contract *is* the interface -- it defines the service operations exposed by the WCF service, which may or may not correspond 1:1 to an unadorned code interface your application.

The Behavior is an implementation of that interface on the host -- for all intents and purposes, "the service."

Answer (score -2):

Contract is contract between client and service provider. It tells what data will be exposed.

Service behavior is behavior of service which tells how service will behave when client will hit the service. Lets suppose if multiple clients are hitting service then whether it is able to handle to request or not, how to handle multiple request, what to do to handle multiple request. These things are handle by behavior of service.

Comment: How exactly does this extremely late answer add any value or anything new to what has already been given?